# How to custom draw a tabbar making a bump and adding a text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, tabbar

Here is my design I 'd like to achieve with flutter:

[image]

I currently custom drawn the + (plus) button.

But now I'd like to make this bump. Once I have it, I'd like to add the text on it.

Comment: "But now I'd like to make this bump" - simply call [cubicTo](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Path/cubicTo.html) twice - you can see how the control points define the curve here: https://cubic-bezier.com/

Comment: Any code snippet for how to apply to a tabbar? And I don't get how to make a custom tab that is taller than the  normal tab. I tried to do it without success